# Eagle CAD license board limitation: area or edges?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I am deciding on which license to get for the currnt Eagle Cad 7.x (December 2015). There are a few options to consider regarding the PCB size limitations:

- Standard: 160mmx100mm routing area
- Pro: 4mx4m
- Make Pro: 160mmx100mm routing area with variable height and width

This is as per their [pricing webpage](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pricing/)

My question is: what if I want to make a board 200mm x 50mm, do I need the Pro version, or can I do with the lesser versions in one design? 
The dimensions are larger than Standard, but the area is smaller.

The question boils down to whether the license limits by the edge dimensions or the area size? The confusion comes in because the Make Pro version says something about edges being variable heights and width...

Anyone has experience pushing the license limitations?

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot exceed either dimension.  Install the freeware and check.

Comment: You can always use smaller routing areas (board dimensions), so this `Make Pro` limitation doesn't make sense to me. I quess it allows a rectangular area of 16000mm², because otherwise it's identical to `Standard`. Even the German site (EAGLE is/was a German software) is literally the same mess.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The freeware seems to allow stretching the board, but I'd like to make sure before I spend considerable USD for the license.

Comment: It looks like there are other differences between the Make editions, one example is that Make Pro is an annual license and Make Personal is perpetual.  Does this mean that you have to pay every year to use Make Pro, or just that you lose tech support after a year? I don't know. They've really complicated their options.  It's disappointing. I would call their support number for clarification before spending money... For what it's worth: Back in V5, you could make non-copper artwork outside of the licensing limits, but you could only place parts or route copper inside.

Comment: @elomage If you don't want to lose money, I think your best option is to [contact them](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/contact/).

Comment: BTW, I'm with @ScottSeidman, otherwise they would advertise the maximum area (in mm², in² or whatever) allowed, not each dimension alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a 200mm by 50mm board, you will run into placement problems past 160mm. 
There are three ways to work around this.

1) You can work around this using a special placement function, but that can be tedious. It also will fail ERC most of the time. (From what I last remember when I tried this back in 5.X)

2) You can buy the Pro license. (My least favorite option personally)

3) You can use a different CAD program. (If you're a hobbyist, then look at KiCad. There are limitations, but board size isn't one.)

In the end, they're your only real options. However, please take it with a grain of salt as my EagleCAD experience stopped past 5.X